# reduce matrix by sum of elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, shrink

I'm sure this is basic, but I can't come up to an easy way to reduce a matrix of population count by grid cell by adding up all the elements of the "small" cells which would fit in the new ones.

My matrix is 720x360 and would like to change it to 360x180. I thought about using imresize with 0.5 scale, and then assume the value per new grid is 4 times the old one.

I fell uneasy doing so though, as I can't find examples of similar cases. It'll be nice to have "sum" or "average" as an "interpolation" option or something like that.

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers

Maria

Comment: So you want to sum over 2x2 blocks? Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? Check `blockproc` or `im2col`

Comment: `conv2` with a 2x2 kernel and taking odd rows/columns would also work.

Comment: blockproc worked perfectly, thank you! it takes a bit longer than imresize but  it works good for this case. I used the function `fun=@(block_struct)nansum(nansum(block_struct.data,1),2);` with blockproc specifying my cell side as [2 2], in case it helps anyone else ;-). Thanks a lot

Comment: Also note that bilinear interpolation **for a scale factor of 0.5** is equivalent to taking the average of the 2x2 neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you both, you saved my day. Sometimes you just get blocked with these things and I've been searching for some hours trying to avoid being silly in front of you ;-). Have a great day!

Comment: Actually I did imresize and multiplied by 4 but the results weren't the same as the sum I did by hand. It was pretty close, but still different. As they're big numbers there might be a roundup that changed the outcome I guess. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
x = randi(10,6,8); % example matrix
bs = [2 2]; % block size
y = col2im(sum(im2col(x, bs, 'distinct'), 1), [1 1], size(x)./bs, 'distinct');
```

**How this works**:

`im2col(... 'distinct')` arranges each distinct block of the given size into a column. `sum(...,1)` then sums each column. Finally, `im2col(..., 'distinct')` arranges the results back into a matrix of reduced size.